# Are the following logically equivalent? $\;p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r) \text{ and }\ (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Determine whether the following pair of statements are logically equivalent or not...

$$p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r) \;\;\text{ and }\;\; (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$$

I am new to logic equations so please bare with me...

I have tried to work our the question by looking at this as an if then statement. I know the brackets have to be worked out first so i worked out $(q \rightarrow r)$ first by saying $(T \rightarrow T) \equiv T$ so $T\rightarrow T$ for the first one which is $T$.

For the second pair I again did the brackets first which turned out to be $T$ and $T \rightarrow  T$ is T?

However I am unaware of is this is the right way of doing this or what $r$ means at all.

Comment: Have you tried developing a logic table? That might make it very easy to determine whether or not these are logically equivalent.

Comment: Unfortunately I am new to logic and would not know how to create a logic table for this question

Comment: Hint: notice that (p -> q) is quivalent to ((not p) or q)

Comment: What happens if $p$ is false?

Comment: Instead of checking every instance with a truth table, you should learn to use the method of analytic tableaux. It becomes a lot more useful when working with a large number of possible instances.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that this is not a duplicate question. However, I have trouble locating one.

Comment: Don't you know *any* method for checking if two formulas are equivalent? It must have been covered in your course, or it wouldn't be on the homework.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Suppose $p$ is false, $q$ is true, and $r$ is false?

Comment: Then both expressions are true! You need $r$ to be false to get different truth-values.

Comment: Yes, indeed, @TonyK. That's what I thought (meant) to type!! I just noted the same as you commented.

Comment: sorry i am very new to this, how do we know if they are false? I thought it had to have the not symbol in front of the the letter to show that?

Comment: We don't know whether p, q, r are true or false. But two statements are equivalent if and only if, under *each and every*  possible truth assignment to the variables, both statements evaluate to the same truth value. You showed that under one assignment, both statements are true. I showed that under a different truth assignment, one evaluates to true, and other to false. Since there exists a truth value assignment under which one evaluates to true, the other to false, the statements cannot be equivalent.

Comment: okay i understand now, so to work out the answer you have to work out all propositions and if they are all true then they are equivalent and if even one truth assignment is false then they cant be equivalent? Wonderful thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome, @Phill!

Answer (score 0):

[**I would like to note that the explanation below is INCORRECT. Check comments for details**]

Is this necessarily the only strategy to test for equivalence between two prop statements involving implications? It seems very exhaustive to me. I've read in the comments to try analytics using method of analytic tableau but I have no contextual understanding to begin learning it.

Looking at this problem, though, I would start by recalling the definition of equivalence: those two statements are equivalent if they have the same true values for all corresponding permutations of truth values for p,q,r. I notice that they have the same form: they're both implications (albeit either the hypothesis and conclusion are also an implication). Implications are true for all permutations of truth values except for when the hypothesis is true and the conclusion is false.

Thus if these two implications were to be equivalent, they must be false for the same permutation of truth values of p,q,r that make one statement false. So, pick either one of the implications and find p,q,r that makes that implication false. Then check with the same truth values of p,q,r for the other implication to see if that is false. If they are both false for the same permutation of truth values of p,q,r they are equivalent, otherwise they aren't.

$p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ is false is false if $(q \rightarrow r)$ is false, which happens when $q$ is true and $r$ is false. Thus we need to check the case where $p$ is true, $q$ is true, $r$ is false.

You will see that  the other statement will also be false given this permutation. Thus they are equivalent.

Comment: You are incorrect. $p \rightarrow (q\rightarrow r)$ is false if and only if *$p$ is true and* $q \rightarrow r$ is false. Since under the assignment  $p = F$, $q$ true, r false, we have $F\rightarrow F  = T$. In $(p \rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$, the antecedent is true (because p is false) and the consequent, r, is false. $T\rightarrow F =  F$. So the two expressions cannot be equivalent.

Comment: You're right! It seems my strategy is insufficient...  In this case it seems the best strategy would seem to be to recognize that the first statement can only be false for one permutation and to try to find some other permutation that would make the second statement false. Confirming that the first permutation gives the same truth value does not guarantee equivalence, but finding a permutation for which truth values differ does guarantee non equivalence.

Comment: In this case, we observe that the first statement is false for one permutation and true for all other permutations. At this point, we can either try all permutations (exhaustive), or we can try looking for inequivalence by finding a different permutation such that the second statement is false, which is quite easy: r must be left false but pq can be TT or pq is FT, or pq is FF.